# How can I improve the questions shown to me on main page?

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter

The questions shown to me on the main page are very poor quality (to me), e.g. questions about Java, Android and JavaScript, but I do not follow any tags related with that. How can improve that? How to flag a question or a tag as "not interesting"?

I understand some random questions of any areas should be shown, I don't care if I have two or three questions per day about Java or Android for example (even because I can answer some of them, I'm Java and Android programmer), but now I'm working with [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) and [Clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure), I want to see *more* about this.

Comment: Put [tag:java] in your ignored tags list.

Comment: In the right sidebar on the home page.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but I want to receive sometimes questions from the tags that I put on ignore, but with low priority. Is it possible or is request too much? Thank you.

Comment: A button "show less this" or "show more this" would be very cool in each question. It could be hidden, I don't care :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using favorite and ignore tags. You can add/remove favorite and ignore tags on the right sidebar, or go to your profile page and click on preferences.

For example :

Here are my favorite tags: *Any question that includes 1 or more favorite tags gets highlighted, so it's more noticeable.*

[image]

Here are my ignored tags: *Any question that includes 1 or more ignore tags does not get shown at all.*

[image]

Comment: That's a rather impressive ignore list

Comment: It does not look too smart (a robot job!), StackOverflow could improve this using some smart algo. Sometimes we (or me at least) want to see ignored tags. SOMETIMES.

Comment: ... Don't you ever think you may have too many "ignore"s there? Lots of questions get tagged inappropriately.